# $A \in M_3(\mathbb{C})$, $A$ isn't a diagonalizable matrix., $tr(A)=-3$ $(A+I)(A-I)^2(A+2I)^3=0$ Find jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra

$A \in M_3(\mathbb{C})$, $A$ isn't a diagonalizable matrix., $tr(A)=-3$

$(A+I)(A-I)^2(A+2I)^3=0$

Find jordan normal form

My solution:

$(A+I)(A-I)^2(A+2I)^3=0 \implies p(t)=(t+1)(t-1)^2(t+2)^3=0, p(A)=0$

The minimal polynomial divides $p(t)$.

In addition $tr(A)=-3$ and $A$ isn't a diagonalizable matrix then the appropriate minimal polynomials are only $(t+1)^3 , (t+2)^2(t-1)$

For $(t+1)^3 \implies J =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

For $(t+2)^2(t-1) \implies J =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    -2 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & -2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

I can't get which one is the correct one .

Thanks

Comment: You should check whether these two J meet the polynomial. As long as I've seen, one of that doesn't satisfy

Comment: WHich one doesn't meet the polynomial? can't see it

Comment: The one corresponding to $(t+1)^3$. This is not a divisor of $(t+1)(t-1)^2(t+2)^3$

Comment: You are missing a case in your list of possible minimal polynomials: $(t+1)^2$, which correponds to a Jordan normal form with 2 Jordan blocks both with eigenvalue $-1$.